networkx graph get groups of linked/connected values with multiple values
If I use such data
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 6)])
print(list(nx.connected_components(G)))


Everything works fine.
But what if I need to get connected values from multiple tuple,
such as the folowing
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (1, 3, 7), (2, 4, 1, 6), (5, 6)])
print(list(nx.connected_components(G)))

As you can see its not classic and not working.
What methods can I implement in order to pass such data, so that
I got connected array values?
I expect getting arrays with connected values between each other

The issue is that add_edges_from only takes a list of (source, target) tuples.
You could use itertools:
import networkx as nx
from itertools import chain, pairwise

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

edges = [(1, 2), (1, 3, 7), (2, 4, 1, 6), (5, 6)]
G.add_edges_from(chain.from_iterable(map(pairwise, edges)))

print(list(nx.connected_components(G)))

Variant without import:
G.add_edges_from(e for t in edges for e in zip(t, t[1:]))

Output:
[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}]

Graph:

Intermediates:
# list(chain.from_iterable(map(pairwise, edges)))
# [e for t in edges for e in zip(t, t[1:])]

[(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 7), (2, 4), (4, 1), (1, 6), (5, 6)]


Cool, thanks! Cause I did in awful way and your variant is much more readable
